# Disable CS-Cart compilation

Tags: php, compilation, cs-cart

Is there a way to disable compilation in `var/compiled` globally in CS-Cart?

I am using CS-Cart version 2.2.4

Here is what I have defined in `config.local.php`:

```
define('DEVELOPMENT', true);

// Tweaks
$config['tweaks'] = array(
    'js_compression' => false, // enables compession to reduce size of javascript files
    'check_templates' => true, // disables templates checking to improve template engine speed
    'inline_compilation' => false, // compiles nested templates in one file
    'anti_csfr' => false, // protect forms from CSFR attacks (experimental)
    'disable_block_cache' => true, // used to disable block cache
    'join_css' => false, // is used to unite css files into one file
    'allow_php_in_templates' => false, // Allow to use {php} tags in templates
);
```

I also set *development mode* in the backend but that doesn't seem to change anything.

When editing a .tpl in an addon, I still need to delete `var/compiled` to see my changes. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

After you enable development mode you are able to clear the cache from frontend by adding cc variable to the any url ex: http://www.example.com/?cc or http://www.example.com/monitors/?cc or http://www.example.com/apple-iphone-5c-32gb-cell-phone-green.html?cc or http://www.example.com/index.php?dispatch=categories.view&category_id=1&cc

Comment: I think I tried that and it didn't work either. I'll try again tomorrow and let you know. Thanks for the reply anyway!